# Extra record showing in ActiveRecord query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So here's the problem:

I have a page where I want a list of 'items' displayed.  I also want to have a form on this page used for adding additional 'items'.

The 'new' action in the controller looks like this:

```html
def new
  @collection = current_user.collections.find_by_id(params[:collection_id])
  @item_list = @collection.items
  
  @item = @collection.items.new
end
```

The code in the view like this:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div id="main_area" class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="center">
      <h3><%= @collection.title %></h3>
      <% if @item_list.any? %>
        <ul>
          <% @item_list.each do |il| %>
            <li>
              <%=i l.name %>
                <% end %>
        </ul>
        <% end %>

          <div id="add_item">
            <%=f orm_for [@collection, @item] do |f| %>
              <div class="form-group <%= 'has-error has-feedback' if @item.errors[:name].present? %>">
                <label class="sr-only" for="item_name">Item Name</label>
                <%=f .text_field :name, :autofocus=>true, :placeholder => "Item Name", :class => "form-control", :'aria-describedBy' => "itemNameBlock" %>
                  <% if @collection.errors[:title].present? %>
                    <span id="itemNameBlock" class="error">Item <%= @item.errors[:name].first %></span>
                    <% end %>
              </div>
              <div id="signin_button_row">
                <%=f .submit "Save", :class=>"form-control green_button" %>
                  <span id="forgot_my_password" class="right-justify">
      <%= link_to "cancel", collection_items_path(@collection), :class => "new_colors terms" %>
     </span>
              </div>
              <% end %>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the fact that the loop in the view always seems to have one extra 'item' in it, and this seems to be related to the fact that I'm using 'new' in the controller.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the same item but not add it to the collection

```
def new
  @collection = current_user.collections.find_by_id(params[:collection_id])
  @item_list = @collection.items

  @item = Item.new collection_id: @collection.id
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like this solution as it separates the @item from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when building a template Item object you're putting it to the collection as well, which is not what you want.

To me it looks like there are two possible fixes for this:

1. Do not display the new item by checking whether the item has been persisted or not when outputting a list:

   ```
   <ul>
     <% @item_list.reject(&:new?).each do |il| %>
       <li>
         <%= il.name %>
       </li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Do not actually add the new template item to the collection, which makes more sense to me from the conceptual point of view, since you actually don't need that item to be associated with your items collection at the point of rendering the view, e.g.:

   ```
   class ItemsController < ApplicationController

     before_filter do
       @collection = collection.find(params[:collection_id])
       @items = @collection.items
     end

     def index
       @item = Item.new
     end

     def create
       @item = @items.new(item_params)
       if @item.save
         redirect_to  collection_items_path
       else
         render action: :index
       end
     end

     private

     def item_params
       params.require(:item).permit!
     end
   end
   ```

Hope that makes sense and works for you!

Comment: Thanks ... I guess what I was missing that performing a 'find' retrieves all objects, persisted or not.   Theoretically, both solutions could work, and if I had to choose one of the two, I'd likelyselect the first one.